# Anime featuring a boy who was raised aboard a spaceship and a war among robots

Tags: story-identification, anime, space, robots

So this anime is from around 2000 to 2004, I guess. It showed a boy who was raised aboard a spaceship? He keeps having flashbacks of a small baby crying, searching for his parents, with the implication that his parents died on that spaceship. Later on, there's some kind of war among robots and the robot-shaped spaceship wakes up. In the end, they win and the spaceship again stops working?

Answer (score 1):

Just found it, I hope it helps, it's called [*Space Firebird 2772*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_2772). Anyway, that’s the one I was looking for. It checked all the boxes; you saw it in the 2000s, but it's from 1980 (I watched it probably around 1997). It has a different name originally, “*Phoenix 2772*”

The whole movie is on YouTube but won't share link because I don’t know if it goes against the site.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  While a link to the full show might be suspect, you could certainly include some screenshots that show the important details.